# Number of solutions $x$ of equation $a_1 b_1^x + \dotsb + a_n b_n^x=0$ over a finite field

Tags: finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Let $F$ be a finite field and let $a_1, b_1, \dotsc, a_n, b_n \in F$ be field elements. I am interested in the number of solutions $0\leq x \leq |F|-1$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{e:1}
a_1 b_1^x + \dotsb + a_n b_n^x = 0.
\end{equation}

Can we upper bound the number of solutions $x$? How about the special case when $F$ is a field of prime order? Is there any literature available for this problem?

Note: there are choices of $\{a_i, b_i\}$ for which every $0\leq x \leq |F|-1$ is a solution. For example, take $n$ even, $a_1=1, a_2=-1, a_3=1, a_4=-1,\dots$, and $b_1=\dotsb =b_n$. In general, I expect that either the elements $\{a_i, b_i\}$ are such that all $0\leq x\leq|F|-1$ is a solution, as in the example, or that there are "almost no" solutions $x$.

Comment: I'm a little confused about when we call $(a, b)$ trivial.  Is it when there is *some* solution $x$ to $\sum a_i b_i^x = 0$ in $F$ that lifts to a solution over $\mathbb Z$, or when *every* solution $x$ lifts?

Comment: I meant to say that every solution $x$ lifts

Comment: I have edited my question so that it is hopefully more clear now